# what does 'package pkg do ... end' mean in a recipe of a chef cookbook?

Tags: ruby, chef-recipe

I'm a newbie of ruby. I know this statement is used by recipe to update a package:

```
package pkg do
  options platform_options['package_overrides']
  action :upgrade
end
```

I wonder whether the 'package' is a method? I think it should be a method but I can't find the method definition in either Chef::Resource or Chef::Resource::Package class. How does this statement being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically — it is a method call, yes. And you pass an argument `pkg` and a "block" (simply put, an anonymous function) to it.

Inside the method it's able to call the `do .. end` block you supplied. Its simple syntax makes Ruby really convenient as a base for domain-specific languages (DSL) that allows to deliver user's code into a complex system to be executed somewhere deep inside.

But I failed to find which method does it call, but I suppose it's by design, there is no such method: and Ruby calls this instance's `method_missing` in this case. Apparently, [it's defined here](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/dsl/recipe.rb). When executing your code, Ruby implicitly issues the following method call:

```
method_missing :package, pkg do
  options platform_options['package_overrides']
  action :upgrade
end
```